# High usage of RAM causes to slow down an Android app

Tags: android, knockout.js, webview

I'm developing an Android application, which is uses a `WebView` to load website from the assets folder. The website is based on `Knockout.js`, so  almost everything is `dynamic` and `observable` (in terms of `KO`). Besides, it's doing TCP requests every 100 milliseconds and updates a particular part of the view, based on the `response`.

A week ago I realized, that my app is running too slow, then I noticed, that it uses 60-100MB of RAM. I've tried almost all solutions from the web, e.g. disable app cache, disable `WebView` cache, etc., but with no luck.

I also did some tests and noticed, that, for example, a "blank" app (nothing but "HelloWorld") uses 9-10MB of RAM, an app with `WebView`, which simply loads a single URL, uses almost 20MB of RAM.

I've read many articles regarding `WebView` memory leak, but couldn't get to work any of those solutions. I'm really confused.

So, actually, I have two questions:

1. Is it normal for app like this to use 60-100MB of RAM?
2. If yes, why? And if no, which kind of changes/optimizations should I do to have an app which consumes RAM as expected?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm hopefully expecting a working solution.

Comment: "Is it normal for an app like this". An app like what? It's impossible for us to say when the only thing we know is that you are using Knockout and making requests. You may be doing plenty of things to justify that number.

Comment: It's doing the following: 1) Starts a broadcast receiver for network connection. 2) If there is a connection, it loads the website from assets. 3) The website then does an AJAX request to get an XML for layout. 4) Then it generates the view based on that XML. 5) After this, it starts requests every 100 ms (it makes requests from the JavaScript by calling the function of JavaScript interface, so the actual requests are made from Android/Java).

Comment: What is the size of the asset request payload? What is the size of the XML layout? What is the memory footprint once the layout is generated? What are the size of the 100ms requests (or the average size, if they differ)?

Comment: OK, here are the sizes: Asset - 6.22MB; XML - 257KB; One request contain 10~20 5-digit numbers, separated by colon. I've just used MAT to dump HPROF file, which's overview shows only 6.7MB usage, but in the "Running apps" section on device, it still shows 67MB. Shouldn't have these numbers to be equal?

Comment: No, those numbers will probably never be equal. Just look at your test, that showed a single `webview` app consuming 20mb. Besides the assets, anything the system needs will take up memory. If you have a layout that gets populated with data, the system will need to render the layout multiple times.